How to define more than one response body schema in OpenAPI
We have an endpoint with json response as in Code1. There is an user condition and when this is met second version of json with string "Employee" added as in Code2.
I'm trying to document this in OpenAPI and having issues embedding these schema's. Below is my code, but some how getting OpenAPI invalid with "paths must not include query string" and "potentially unused component has been detected errors" and so on. I'm not sure if this is right way of doing it or if there is any better way to achieve this? Any help would be really helpful
Below is my existing json response in for one of the end point as in Code1:
    [
       {
          "EmpId":{
             "String":"ABCD",
             "Valid":true
          },
          "Department":{
             "Float64":0,
             "Valid":true
          }
       }
    ]

We have an optional parameter where the condition is met, below will be the response
    {
       "Employee":[
          {
             "EmpId":{
                "String":"ABCD",
                "Valid":true
             },
             "Department":{
                "Float64":0,
                "Valid":true
             }
          }
       ]
    }

Below is my model to achieve this and we have an if condition within the code to determine which response to get.
    type Employeewithroot struct {
        Employees []Employees `json:"Employee"`
    }
    type Employees struct {
        EmpNbr     sql.NullString  `json:"EmpNbr"`
        DateofJoin      sql.NullString   `json:"DateofJoin"`
        DeptId  sql.NullString  `json:"DeptId"`
        DeptName sql.NullString  `json:"DeptName"`
    }


    openapi: 3.0.1
    info:
      title: API's
      description: >-
        REST API's for abc
      contact:
        name: ABC
        email: ABC
      version: "1.0.0"
    servers:
      - url: "http://localhost:8080/"
    tags:
      - name: Employees     
        description: Get Employees info 
    paths:
      /Employees:
        get:
          description: Get Employee info 
          summary: Get Employee.
          tags:
          - Employees
          security:
          - basicAuth:
            - '[]'
          operationId: GetEmployees
          parameters:
          - name: EmpNbr
            in: query
            description: Employee ID(Example:0123456789)
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
          - name: DateofJoin
            in: query
            description: Input DateofJoin(Example:mmddyyyy(01012023))
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
          responses:
            '200':
              description: OK.
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
      /Employees?EmpNbr={EmpNbr}&DateofJoin={DateofJoin}&cond={cond}:
        get:
          description: Get Employees info as per additional condition 
          summary: Get EmployeeRoot Hdr.
          tags:
          - Employees
          operationId: GetEmployeeRootHdr
          parameters:
          - name: EmpNbr
            in: path
            description: Emp ID(Example:0123456789)
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
          - name: DateofJoin
            in: path
            description: Input DateofJoin(Example:mmddyyyy(01012023))
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
          - name: cond
            in: path
            description: additional check
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
            allowEmptyValue: true      
          responses:
            '200':
              description: OK.
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employeewithroot'
    components:
      schemas:
        Employeewithroot:
          properties:
            Employee:
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
              type: array
              x-go-name: Employees
        Employees:
          properties:
            EmpNbr:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
            DateofJoin:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
            DeptId:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
            DeptName:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
            x-go-package: pkg/model
      securitySchemes:
        basicAuth:
          type: apiKey
          name: Authorization
          in: header    


Added the steps to the question

I'm not a Go developer, so can't help you with the typings.  But I can help you define the OpenAPI, correctly.
this allows you to have a oneOf response (XOR). There is no way to indicate which response will be received in OpenAPI, based on conditional parameters, that logic is left up to your server.
You should not define the query parameters directly in the pathItem Object. They are documented in the Parameters array.
Adding required query parameters is usually a sign of a bad smell in your api design. I would also recommend choosing one type of response and stick with that for consistency.  If your endpoint is a collection response, Employees, always return a collection {"Employees": [{...}, {...} {...}]}.  If the collection is empty, then the service returns a 200, with an empty collection {"Employees": []}. Otherwise, it can return N employees, and the consumer's code only needs to handle one data type, the array, which they can iterate through if more than one record exists.
If you want to query by Emp ID, then I would document a separate endpoint to query by the identifier. (I included that below)
openapi: '3.0.3'
info:
  title: API's
  description: >-
    REST API's for abc
  contact:
    name: ABC
    email: ABC
  version: "1.0.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost:8080"
tags:
  - name: Employees     
    description: Get Employees info 
paths:
  /Employees:
    get:
      description: Get Employees info as per additional condition 
      summary: Get EmployeeRoot Hdr.
      tags:
      - Employees
      operationId: GetEmployeeRootHdr
      security: 
        - basicAuth: []
      parameters:
      - name: EmpNbr  ## This query parameter can be removed if you go with the second endpoint defined below
        in: query
        description: Emp ID
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        examples: 
          Employee_ID:
            value: '0123456789' 
      - name: DateofJoin  ## i would recommend making this query parameter, required: false
        in: query
        description: Input DateofJoin
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        examples: 
          DateofJoin:
            value: '01012023' 
      - name: cond  ## if you go with the Employees Collection response for all requests, this query parameter is not necessary
        in: query
        description: additional check
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        examples:
          Condition:
            value: ''
        allowEmptyValue: true      
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                oneOf: 
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees' ## I would recommend not to use this schema. 
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employeewithroot'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
  '/Employees/{employee-id}':
    get:
      description: Get a single Employee's details.
      summary: Get EmployeeRoot Hdr.
      tags:
      - Employees
      operationId: GetEmployeeByID
      security: 
        - basicAuth: []
      parameters:
      - name: employee-id
        in: path
        required: true
        description: Employee Identifier
        schema: 
          type: string
        examples: 
          Employee_ID:
            value: '0123456789' 
      - name: DateofJoin
        in: query
        description: Input DateofJoin
        required: false
        schema:
          type: string
        examples: 
          DateofJoin:
            value: '01012023'     
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employeewithroot'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
        
components:
  schemas:
    Employeewithroot:
      type: object
      properties:
        Employee:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
          x-go-name: Employees
    Employees:
      type: object
      properties:
        EmpNbr:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DateofJoin:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptName:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
    NullString:
      type: string
      nullable: true
      x-go-package: pkg/model
    ProblemJson:
      description: Problem Details for HTTP APIs - RFC9457
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          format: uri-reference
        status:
          type: number
        title:
          type: string
        detail:
          type: string
        instance:
          type: string
          format: uri-reference
  responses:
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
      content: 
        'application/problem+json':
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProblemJson"
        'application/json':
          ## used if problem+json is not supported
          schema: {}
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header    


We don't want to query by EmpId as the response/condition isn't based on that field. We just wanted to add the root level tag to the original response if that condition is met. Is there a way we could define in such a way that Employeewithroot schema get's selected when the condition is met and Employees schema be selected when condition is blank for the same endpoint in openapi.

Yes, that's exactly what I gave you in the answer with the oneOf response. But as I mentioned, there's no way to define which response will be received based on a conditional parameter in OpenAPI, that must be handled by your server. The purpose of documenting the oneOf is to define to the consumer that they may receive one or the other of these two responses
